# Split CSV in multiple files, reading column 1 for naming output files

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I have an employees.csv file with around 500 rows and 11 columns, column fileds are limited by double quotes:

```
"1","Paula","Paula's Role","Paula's Job Description","Paula's Department","11/10/2008","8","14","10","24","0
"2","John","John's Role","John's Job Description","John's Department","11/10/2008","2","17","6","11","0"
"3","Mark","Mark's Role","Mark's Job Description","Mark's Department","11/10/2008","4","17","13","44","0"
:
:
(more records)
:
:
"499","Maria","Maria's Role","Maria's Job Description","Maria's Department","11/10/2008","8","15","2","9","0"
"500","Peter","Peter's Role","Peters's Job Description","Peters's Department","11/10/2008","8","17","16","22","0"
```

I'm trying to figure out how to split such file in multiple csv (one line = one file), according to the first field (unique employee ID number).
The output of the command shall be 500 separate csv files, containing 1 row each one, and named as follows:

```
1.csv
2.csv
3.csv
:
:
:
499.csv
500.csv
```

I've been trying with combination of cat and awk, but there is some mistake in the code:

```
for i in $(cat unix | awk -F\, '{print $1}' /myfolder/employees.csv);

    do
        grep $i "/myfolder/employees.csv" > "/myfolder/splittedfiles/$i";
    done
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GNU awk like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FPAT="[^\"]+"} { print $0 > "/myfolder/splittedfiles/"$1".csv" }' yourfile
```

`FPAT` defines field content by a regular expression, here it helps us to strip the quotes from `$1`.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Is there some way to put the output files in a separate folder with the same command?  (ie: a folder named splittedfiles)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** (and this one is tested), this `gawk` script does the job for me:

```
gawk -F'"' -- '{print $0 >> ("/myfolder/splittedfiles/" $2 ".csv")}' /myfolder/employees.csv
```

The `-F'"'` splits fields at `"`, so the employee number is in `$2`.  Then `("/myfolder/splittedfiles/" $2 ".csv")` builds the filename you want, and `print $0 >> ...` prints the original line to that file.

---

**Or** if the fields are always in numerical order starting from 1, this should work (not tested)

```
split -l 1 /myfolder/employees.csv /myfolder/splittedfiles/EMPL
empno=1
for fname in /myfolder/splittedfiles/EMPL* ; do
    mv "$f" "/myfolder/splittedfiles/${empno}.csv"
    empno=$((empno+1))
done
```

`split` makes each line (`-l 1`) a separate file.  The `for` loops over those files in order.  The `mv` renames each file to be `${empno}.csv`, starting from `empno=1`.  Then `$((empno+1))` increments `empno`.